# Sum of two squares decomposition counting

Tags: c++, c, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I want to count how many pairs of natural number there are such that a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> = c<sup>2</sup>. As an input to my function I have `c`.

My idea was to first check whether the condition is fulfilled, than if not, I wanted to have a loop iterating desired expression up to `c`. If result is equal to the square of `c` than I wanted to have `count++`. Question is why this is not working?

Some corrections added.

```
int sum(int c) {
    int b=1;
    int a=1;
    int count=0;
    int result;

    if (a*a + b*b != c*c)
    {
        for (int i=1; i<=c; i++)
        {
            b=i;
            result = a*a + b*b;
            if (result == c*c)
                count++;
        }
        a++;
    }
    else
        count++;

    return count;
}
```

The problem is I still do not understand why this does not want to work.

My second idea was to approach it with while loop:

```
int sum(int c) {
    int b=1;
    int a=1;
    int count=0;
    int result;

    if (a*a + b*b != c*c)
    {
        while(b<=c)
        {
            result = a*a + b*b;
            if (result == c*c)
                {count++;
                b++;
                }
                else
                    b++;
        }
        a++;
    }
    else
        count++;

    return count;
}
```

Not working as well.

**Anybody any ideas as to how to make it work? Any of those two versions? Maybe hints?**

Comment: <=c in your for loop?

Comment: Why waste time with `a*a` when you never change the value of `a` from `1`?

Comment: You fix this with a [debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) - step through the code, look at the variables and  you'll understand how everything is working when you're done.

Comment: Please store things in variables. aSquared = a * a; bSquared = b * b; cSquared = c*c; if(aSquared + bSquared != cSquared), readability would help others too.....

Comment: And your count is not initialized to 0 so when you do count++ its doing junk ++

Comment: I have added some corrections and still not functioning properly.

Comment: I was trying to attempt this question with loop while but still does not work.

Comment: How to improve my code?

Comment: I [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35281353/4944425) a vaguely related question, some time ago. See if the code I used can help you.

Comment: I do not understand how to use your code in my case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using an `if` expecting it to work like a loop.  At the bottom of the `if` you're incrementing `a`, however because it is an `if` and not a `while` or `for`, it doesn't jump back up to the top.

Both `a` and `b` need to change, so you need a loop to control each one.

```
for (a=1; a<=c; a++) {
    for (b=a; b<=c; b++) {
        if (a*a + b*b == c*c) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `b` starts at the current value of `a` instead of 1.  That way, you aren't trying the same pair of numbers (just switched) twice.